# How does a market order actually get filled?

Tags: stocks

If I have a buy market order, there are three selling orders as follow:

1. Sell limit order @ $10
2. Sell limit order @ $11
3. Sell @ market order

How will my order get filled?

Comment: It seems like you ask a lot of (hypothetical) questions about the stock market. It would be great if you could [upvote/accept answers that address your question](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) or leave a comment if you think anything is missing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because unfortunately OP is asking many vague/general questions, and indeed never Servicing the votes/ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A market order does not "enter" the Order Book.

It is either **instantly** matched with an existing Limit Order, or Rejected.

Therefore, by the time time you submit your "buy market order", the "Sell @ market order" does not exist in the Order Book.

The only exception is Opening/Closing auction, in which both Buy Market Order and Sell Market Order can exist at the same time right before Opening/Closing. The price is determined by other Limit Orders that result in maximum volume transacted.